# How to estimate Distance to Obstacles using Lidar's BEV(Bir's Eye view ) Representation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I am using a implementation that use both camera and Lidar for 3D obstacle detection for self driving cars but I have no idea how to calculate the distance to the obstacles since the Lidar uses the Bird's Eye View ?